# Use Laplace transform to solve the system

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = -y$ , $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}  = x.$

For $t\geq 0$ , with $x(0) = 1$, $y(0) = 0$.

I have no clue on how to start the question. Could some please give me a lead.

The answer is 
$x(t) = \cos(t)$ and $y(t) = \sin(t)$

Comment: The way to work: Take the Laplace transform of both equations. Use the formula for the Laplace transform of a derivative. Then solve an algebraic system of equations, and take inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Solving with out using Laplace transformation (if you are allowed):
we have $ x''(t)=-y'(t)=-x(t)$  and so  your equation is  $x''(t)+x(t)=0$ It is a lnear homogenous differential equation second order with constant coeffitients. You can use [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/diffeq/diffeq.html)  site  to find the solution.